# Building a custom Debian CD with simple-cdd : rebuild without downloading all the deb files

Tags: debian, proxy

I am building a custom Debian CD to setup a small server with apache and our softwares, and I use simple-cdd wich seems nice, but a little buggy.

Each time I want to add a new custom DEB file, I have to delete the tmp directory, and simple-cdd download all deb stuff. If I do not delete the tmp dir, I do not have my new deb files included.
I try approx and --debian-mirror http://localhost:9999/debian parameter, but it do not change anything, and it get time to rebuild my CD because of the huge download.

How to speed up things?

Best regards,
Cédric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approx well configured is just the best solution, dowloading only needed files.